# when one-to-one relation should I store everything in object or in dedicated storage?

Tags: oop

Assume we have class `Car` which MAIN field is called `VIN` (Vehicle Identification Number). VIN gives us a lot of information such us:

- owner
- place of registration
- country of production
- year of production
- color
- engine type
- etc. etc

I can continue and add more information:

- last known GPS coordinates
- fine list
- is theft (boolean)
- etc. etc.

It seems reasonable to store some of information (for example year of production and engine type) right inside `Car` object. However storing all this information right inside `Car` object will make it too complicated, "overloaded" and hard to manage. Moreover while application evolves I can add more and more information.

So where is the border? What should be stored inside `Car` object and what should be stored outside in something like `Dictionary<Car, GPSCoordinates>`

I think that probably I should store "static" data inside `Car` object so making it `immutable`. And store "dynamic" data in special storages.

Comment: Just an idea. A Car class and a derived RunningCar class. To differentiate the status from as 'out of the dealer' and a working one

Comment: @Steve i don't like that as the same car need to change it instance from `RunningCar` to `Car` and back what extremely inconvenient. i expect to be one real object = one instance.

Answer (score 0):

Just because your `Car` class provide a **property** `GPSCoordinates` does not mean you need to hold those coordinates internally. Essentially, that's what encapsulation is all about.

And yes, you can then add properties such as "IsInGarageNow", "WasEverDrivedByMadonna" or "RecommendedOil".

Answer (score 0):

I would use a class called `CarModel` for the base attributes shared by every possible car in your application (engine size, color, registration #, etc). You can then extend this class with any number of more specific subclasses like Car, RentalCar, or whatever fits your business logic.

This way you have one clear definition of what all cars share and additional definitions for the different states cars can be in (RentalCar with its unique parameters, for example).

**Update:**

I guess what you're looking for is something like this (although I would recommend against it):

```
public class Car
{
   // mandatory
   protected int engineSize;
   protected int color;

   // optional
   protected Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<String, Object>();


   public void set(String name, Object value)
   {
     attributes.put(name, value);
   }

   public Object get(String name)
   {
     return attributes.get(name);
   }
}
```

**Why this is not a good solution:**

- Good luck trying to persist this class to a database or design anything that relies on a well known set of attributes for it.
- Nightmare to debug potential problems.
- Not a very good use of OOP with regard to type definitions. This can be abused to turn the `Car` class into something it is not.

Comment: i'm talking only about parameters applicable to any Car. and I can imagine a lot of such parameters. For example "IsInGarageNow", "WasEverDrivedByMadonna" or "RecommendedOil". So application often need to store a lot of information. But what information should I store in object and what information should I store outside of object..

Comment: Well, given that this is OOP you're talking about, there should really not be anything *not* encapsulated inside the `Car` class or one of its deriving classes. At some point, you do have to decide what defines a type (Car, in this example). There are ways to allow a class to hold an arbitrary number of values beyond its mandatory parameters, but I would really question the validity of using such a solution, unless you absolutely have to.